How can I run jobs in Spring Batch 5.x without creating Batch Metadata entries in Database
As per Spring Batch 5.x, we have to create meta data table in our DB and because of that I am seeing lots of entries in our DB which I am trying to avoid. Is there a way I can avoid job entries in DB ?
Having some task executor to delete those after jobs run.

Can you describe what records you intend to delete?

You could consider the use of an in-memory database such as H2 for storing spring batch metadata, this allows the metadata to be stored temporarily and will be cleared when the application stops.
Alternatively, use a custom JobListener by extending JobExecutionListener to clean up the metadata.
Hope it helps.
